# How to terminate empty infinite loop thread without using Thread.stop

Tags: multithreading, infinite-loop, interrupt, executorservice

One of my Runnable runs following code:

```
while(true) {}
```

I have tried wrapping that Runnable in Executor apis and then tried shutdown method. Tried thread.interrupt. but nothing works. I can not modify Runnable code. Any suggestions...

Comment: Don't do that, basically. You should avoid terminating threads like this anyway - give your runnable a flag to check periodically.

Comment: You are right. But, is there anyway to terminate such thread without using its stop method.

Comment: If the thread isn't set up to allow cancellation (i.e. it's not looking to see if it is supposed to terminate), then the only way to stop it is to abort it. So, as Jon Skeet said, "don't do that."

Comment: Make it as a daemon thread. Then it will automatically end when the main thread exits.

Answer (score 1):

Check its interrupted flag:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {}
```

Most of the Executors interrupt worker threads on `shutdownNow`, so this gives you a tidy mechanism for a clean shutdown.

If you need to terminate the `Runnable` outside the context of an `Executor`, you'll need to give it a `shutdown` method that sets a flag.

```
final AtomicBoolean isShutdown = new AtomicBoolean();
public void shutdown() {
    if (!isShutdown.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !isShutdown.get()) {}
}
```